# Matching the closest string to another string (football teams)?

Tags: python-3.x, string, levenshtein-distance

I am working on standardising some data I'm receiving through a football API.

I have a function with three inputs, `home`, `away` (two football teams) & a list of strings which contain the team `home` or `away`, but they may be named differently to the input `home` and `away`.

My goal is to replace all instances of `home` in the list with 1 and all instances of `away` in the list with 2.

Here are some example inputs:

```
home: "Manchester United", away: "Liverpool", list = ["Man Utd and Yes", "Liverpool and No", "Man Utd and No", "Liverpool and Yes"]

home: "Manchester United", away: "Manchester City", list = ["Man Utd and Yes", "Man City and No", "Man Utd and No", "Man City and Yes"]

home: "Paris Saint Germain", away: "Monaco", list = ["Monaco and Yes", "Monaco and No", "PSG and Yes", "PSG and No"]

home: "Brighton & Hove Albion", away: "Chelsea", list = ["Chelsea and No", "Brighton and Yes", "Chelsea and Yes", "Brighton and No"]
```

Note, the names of the teams within the list are consistent (you would never see "Manchester United and Yes", "Man Utd and No" within the same list).

Now, how do I match the teams? This is what I've done so far:

```
def standardise(home, away, lst):
   for i, v in enumerate(lst):
      team = v.split("and")[0]
   
      if team in home or home in team:
         lst[i] = v.replace(team, "1")
         for j, k in enumerate(lst):
            new_team = k.split("and")[0]
            if new_team != i and team != new_team:
               lst[j] = k.replace(new_team, "2")
            else:
               lst[j] = k.replace(new_team, "1")
         
      elif team in away or away in team:
         # same code as above but for away 

      elif enchant.utils.levenshtein(team, home) >= \
           enchant.utils.levenshtein(team, away):
      
         lst[i] = v.replace(team, "2")

      else:
         lst[i] = v.replace(team, "1")
```

Where the Levenshtein distance measures the minimum number of edits that you need to do to change a one-word sequence into the other.

Now, this method doesn't work 100% of the time, for example, with acronyms, the method seems to fail.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps a more concrete method somebody can think of?

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzywuzzy is perfect for this. pretty simply [docs](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) too

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def standardise(home, away, lst):
    home_away = {home:'1', away:'2'}
    choices = [home, away]
    
    print ([ home_away[process.extractOne(each, choices)[0]] for each in lst ])


home = "Manchester United"
away = "Liverpool", 
lst = ["Man Utd and Yes", "Liverpool and No", "Man Utd and No", "Liverpool and Yes"]
standardise(home, away, lst)


home = "Manchester United" 
away = "Manchester City" 
lst = ["Man Utd and Yes", "Man City and No", "Man Utd and No", "Man City and Yes"]
standardise(home, away, lst)


home = "Paris Saint Germain" 
away = "Monaco" 
lst = ["Monaco and Yes", "Monaco and No", "PSG and Yes", "PSG and No"]
standardise(home, away, lst)


home = "Brighton & Hove Albion" 
away = "Chelsea" 
lst = ["Chelsea and No", "Brighton and Yes", "Chelsea and Yes", "Brighton and No"]
standardise(home, away, lst)
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '2', '1', '2']
['1', '2', '1', '2']
['2', '2', '1', '1']
['2', '1', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dropping vowels first, so each name will be closer to its acronym, and then apply Levenshtein.

And check [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) too.